# How to remove the decimal place when number before decimal is 0

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to remove the decimal places from certain values

for example, my current code is

```
select po_id, AVG(price*quantity) * count(*) AS 'Total Cost'
from po_items natural join items 
group by po_id;
```

this is the output im getting

```
po_id       Total Cost
----------  ----------
AAA         2217.5
BBB         255.0
CCC         5787.5
DDD         10000.0
GGG         1000.0
```

and the output im trying to get is

```
po_id       Total Cost
----------  ----------
AAA         2217.5
BBB         255
CCC         5787.5
DDD         10000
GGG         1000
```

Comment: same column output data type should be the same otherwise you have to make it string which can you do in application layer

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: You use sqlite?

Comment: Yep thats what im using

Comment: @Shawn.X any idea on how to fix it? i think maybe the AVG()*count can be replaced

Comment: @Tarkoman09 see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as below:

```
sqlite> select cost from my_table;
2217.5
255.0
5787.5
10000.0
1000.0

sqlite> select replace(cast(cost as string),'.0','') from my_table;
2217.5
255
5787.5
10000
1000
```

Your complete SQL maybe:

```
select 
    po_id, 
    replace(cast(avg(price*quantity)*count(1) as string),'.0','') as 'Total Cost'
from 
    po_items
join 
    items 
group by 
    po_id;
```

Comment: I worked this well on my local sqlite3 database. you just use `replace(cast(cost as string),'.0','')` to remove the `'.0'` characters. @Tarkoman09

Comment: maybe im not structuring it correctly, could you show me how it would work with my table names etc and using the natural join

Comment: This is on the right track but I have to use a natural join

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf()` with the `%g` format specifier:

```
sqlite> select printf('%g', 5.0), printf('%g', 5.5);
printf('%g', 5.0)  printf('%g', 5.5)
-----------------  -----------------
5                  5.5
```

Comment: if you can see my code, where would i add  replace(cast(cost as string),'.0','')

Comment: We two Shawn meet here. :)